# Changing the username of a portal user

Tags: email, portal

I have changed the username of a portal user  but  the user didn receive any notification about username changed. On the other hand when I change the username of a normal user then email is received by the user. Can any one help me  why the portal user didn receive the email notification.

Comment: what does the Email log says? Setup -> Logs -> Email Log Files

Comment: Is both type users were active when you change the user name? By default I don't see the scenario to auto send any email unless you checked "Generate new password and notify user immediately". Interestingly I am not seeing this check box for Community user page!!