# No email notification when Username is changed for Community User

Tags: community, email, user-management, user-record

When I change the username of the Community user ( any community license) from user record page in SFDC , I don't see any email notification from salesforce sent to the user notifying of username change.
Same scenario when executed for internal users, SFDC sends email notification.
I also checked email logs and don't see any notification email in the log.

Is this the default behavior ?
Is there a way to send out notification when username is changed for community users ( from standard SFDC user record or from user record update from data loader)

Comment: Is community user active?

Comment: I have found [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71656/changing-the-username-of-a-portal-user) with same problem, however a viable workaround should be creating a workflow or process to send this email upon username change

Comment: @Reshma, yes the community user is active